# ant-contrib for loop and regex in ant scripting

Tags: regex, ant, ant-contrib

I have a requirement using ant, that the target should extract the two parameters passed as comma separated in a long list of similar pair of parameters passed which are semicolon separated. Currently I am doing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="" basedir="." default="test" xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">
<target name="test" >
<echo message="Hey There I am using What's App" />
<ac:for list="asdfg,dasfdf;vxxexqxx,hyyypyly;dksfgsgdgf,abaifuacu" delimiter=";" param="val">
<ac:sequential>
<ac:propertyregex property="param1"
            input="@{val}"
            regexp="([^\.]*)\,.*"
            select="\1"
            casesensitive="true" />
<ac:propertyregex property="param2"
            input="@{val}"
            regexp=".*,([^\.]*)"
            select="\1"
            casesensitive="true" />
<echo message = "val = ${param1}"/>
<echo message = "value = ${param2}"/>
</ac:sequential>
</ac:for>
</target>
</project>
```

But I am getting the output as:

```
Buildfile: /tmp/Manish/build.xml

test:
 [echo] Hey There I am using What's App
 [echo] val = asdfg
 [echo] value = dasfdf
 [echo] val = asdfg
 [echo] value = dasfdf
 [echo] val = asdfg
 [echo] value = dasfdf
```

So this is getting looped 3 times(correct) but by only the first value passed in the for loop parameter. Is there some obvious mistake I am making?

Thanks,
Manish Joshi

Comment: you're missing a big thing about ant:  it's not a scripting language.  properties are not variables - they're immutable.  You're requirement doesn't match your tooling.  there are no parameters in ant.

Comment: There are parameters in ant. That's what macrodef is for. It always amuses me how few people now about macrodef and try to do everything with targets leading to overly complex and unmaintainable ant scripts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Properties in Ant are immutable.  You will need to use the [variable task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) from ant-contrib (although it is discouraged) to unset the properties:

```
<ac:for list="asdfg,dasfdf;vxxexqxx,hyyypyly;dksfgsgdgf,abaifuacu" delimiter=";" param="val">
<ac:sequential>
<ac:propertyregex property="param1"
            input="@{val}"
            regexp="([^\.]*)\,.*"
            select="\1"
            casesensitive="true" />
<ac:propertyregex property="param2"
            input="@{val}"
            regexp=".*,([^\.]*)"
            select="\1"
            casesensitive="true" />
<echo message = "val = ${param1}"/>
<echo message = "value = ${param2}"/>
<ac:var name="param1" unset="true"/>
<ac:var name="param2" unset="true"/>
</ac:sequential>
</ac:for>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using foreach instead of for and put the propertyregex into a separate target. Here is an example from my ant script, it basically does the same thing.

```
<target name="loadTestStatic" depends="setTargetEnv,setPassword">
    <loadfile property="controlFile" srcFile="${projectDir}/test/config/static/controlFile.txt"/>

    <foreach list="${controlFile}" delimiter="${line.separator}" param="descriptor" target="loadConfig"/>
</target>

<target name="loadConfig">
    <if>
        <matches string="${descriptor}" pattern="^camTool:"/>
        <then>
            <propertyregex property="camToolFile"
                           input="${descriptor}"
                           regexp="camTool:(.*)"
                           select="\1"
                           casesensitive="false" />
            <echo message="Got cam tool file ${camToolFile}"/>
            <camTool file="${camToolFile}"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <!-- todo: add CM Tool, SQL as required -->
            <echo message="Unexpected config ${descriptor} ignored"/>
        </else>
    </if>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use a scripting language like [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task).

```
  <groovy>
     <arg value="asdfg,dasfdf;vxxexqxx,hyyypyly;dksfgsgdgf,abaifuacu"/>

     args[0].tokenize(";").each {
        def m = it.tokenize(",")

        println "val   = ${m[0]}"
        println "value = ${m[1]}"
     }
  </groovy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use Ant addon [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/), f.e. :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

<!-- with cvs property -->
<property name="foobar" value="asdfg,dasfdf;vxxexqxx,hyyypyly;dksfgsgdgf,abaifuacu"/>
 <fl:for var="item" in="split('${foobar}', ';')">
  <fl:let>
   param1 ::= split(item, ',')[0]
   param2 ::= split(item, ',')[1]
  </fl:let>
  <echo>
   $${param1} => ${param1}
   $${param2} => ${param2}
  </echo>
 </fl:for>

 <!-- with list inline -->
 <fl:for var="item" in="split('asdfg,dasfdf;vxxexqxx,hyyypyly;dksfgsgdgf,abaifuacu', ';')">
  <fl:let>
   param1 ::= split(item, ',')[0]
   param2 ::= split(item, ',')[1]
  </fl:let>
  <echo>
   $${param1} => ${param1}
   $${param2} => ${param2}
  </echo>
 </fl:for>

</project>
```

Notice the double '::' in param1 ::= split(item, ',')[0]
means overriding any (also userproperties, defined via -Dkey=value as commandline arguments) existing property
whereas ':=' creates a property but won't overwrite if property already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="myTarget">
        <ac:propertyregex property="param1"
                input="${myValue}"
                regexp="([^\.]*)\,.*"
                select="\1"
                casesensitive="true" />
        <ac:propertyregex property="param2"
                input="${myValue}"
                regexp=".*,([^\.]*)"
                select="\1"
                casesensitive="true" />
        <echo message = "val = ${param1}"/>
        <echo message = "value = ${param2}"/>
    </target>

    <ac:for list="asdfg,dasfdf;vxxexqxx,hyyypyly;dksfgsgdgf,abaifuacu" delimiter=";" param="val">
    <ac:sequential>
        <antcall target="myTarget">
            <param name="myValue" value="@{val}" />
        </antcall>  
    </ac:sequential>
    </ac:for>
```